# TeamCity not recognizing configuration parameters

Tags: powershell, parameters, teamcity

I have written this script

```
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load(".\build\DashboardUITests.dll.config")
$xml.configuration.appSettings.add |Where-Object {$_.key -eq 'Browser'}|% {$_.value = '%Config_Browser%'}
$xml.configuration.appSettings.add |Where-Object {$_.key -eq 'Environment'}|% {$_.value = '%Config_Enviroment%'}
$xml.configuration.appSettings.add |Where-Object {$_.key -eq 'baseUrl'}|% {$_.value = '%Config_URL%'}
$xml.Save(".\build\DashboardUITests.dll.config")
```

And have created these three build parameters in the build config I am using.

```
Config_Browser = googlechrome
Config_Enviroment = MyEnviroment
Config_URL = BigUrl
```

At the moment the script will show something like this in the dll.config

```
<add key="browser" value="%Config_Browser%" />
```

According to the TC documentation Config parameters require no prefix

"Configuration parameters (no prefix) are not passed into the build and are only meant to share settings within a build configuration. They are the primary means for customizing a build configuration which is based on a template or uses a meta-runner ."

For some reason my script only recognizes these parameters when I prefix them with another "%" for example

```
$xml.configuration.appSettings.add |Where-Object {$_.key -eq 'Browser'}|% {$_.value = '%%Config_Browser%'}
```

Would show something like this in the dll.config

```
<add key="browser" value="%%googlechrome%" />
```

Why is my script not recognizing my created parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet that the powershell piping is causing the issue because it is also using the % character. I would try replacing this alias with [`foreach`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176828.aspx) instead and the build config parameter replacement should work as expected.